# dimension of vector space such that $MN=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix $\displaystyle M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &-1 \\ 
0 &1  &0 \\ 
1 &1  &-1 
\end{bmatrix}$ and let $S_M$ be the set of $3\times3$ matrices N such that $MN=0$ . Then the dimension of the real vector space $S_M$ is equal to ............

My Attempt: The only way $MN=0$ can be zero is when N is a $3\times3$ null matrix. So, its dimension should be 1.

Am I right ?

Comment: No, consider the matrix $N$ whose columns are all $[1, 0, 1]^T$; what is $MN$ in that case?

Comment: @Travis .. Now that I think about this again, a null matrix should not be a part of a basis. and your matrix should form the basis. Am I right now ?

Comment: But how do you know that MN=0 imply N is a null matrix? @square-one

Comment: No, see the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We see that the third column of $M$ is the opposite of the first one so we see easily that $\operatorname{rank }M=2$ and then by the rank-nullity theorem we have $\ker M=1$.

Now it's clear that

$$MN=0\iff \operatorname{im}N\subset \ker M$$
hence
$$\operatorname{rank }N\le 1$$
and then the columns of $N$ are collinear. We conclude that $\dim S_M=3$.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of the kernel of $M$ is $1$. (Proof?) So there is some nonzero vector $v$ such that the kernel consists precisely of the scalar multiples of $v$.

A matrix $N$ satisfies $MN = 0$ if and only if all of the columns of $N$ are in the kernel of $M$. Therefore each column of $N$ must be a scalar multiple of $v$. Since $N$ has three columns, this means I can freely choose the three scalar multiples, and this uniquely determines $N$. Therefore the dimension of $S_M$ is $3$.